# AG-Grid Header Cell Selection

Tags: javascript, selection, ag-grid

I am trying to create an AG-grid to assign permissions in which the Header Selection should select all the cells available in that column.

It should be something like this : 
[image]

One way is to create the Header using HTML template and Cell-Renderer for the rows.

Is there a way I can achieve this using AG-Grid Properties or API?

Comment: Use Ag-grid [Header Components](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-header-rendering/), you can try ``<div class="ag-header-select-all"></div>`` ==> checkbox for selection, if turned on. the grid usually floats this element to the left.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Header Checkbox Selection](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-selection/) examples in Ag-grid documentation.

**Header Checkbox Selection**

> It is possible to have a checkbox in the header for selection. To configure the column to have checkbox, set colDef.headerCheckboxSelection=true. headerCheckboxSelection can also be a function, if you want the checkbox to appear sometimes (eg if the columns is ordered first in the grid).

```
// the name column header always has a checkbox in the header
colDef = {
    field: 'name',
    headerCheckboxSelection: true
    ...
}

// the country column header only has checkbox if it is the first column
colDef = {
    field: 'country',
    headerCheckboxSelection: function(params) {
        var displayedColumns = params.columnApi.getAllDisplayedColumns();
        var thisIsFirstColumn = displayedColumns[0] === params.column;
        return thisIsFirstColumn;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I want the Header selection to check only the cells present in that column only, headerCheckboxSelection selects all the rows rather than corresponding cells.